# corda Failed to set postgreSQL database property url

Tags: java, kotlin, corda

... corda deployNodes fails. The log shows:

> [ERROR] 2018-10-04T11:16:05,466Z [main] util.PropertyElf.setProperty -
>   Failed to set property url on target class
>   org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource {}
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_181]
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_181]
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
>           at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.PropertyElf.setProperty(PropertyElf.java:146)
>   ~[HikariCP-2.5.1.jar:?]
>           at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.PropertyElf.lambda$setTargetFromProperties$0(PropertyElf.java:57)
>   ~[HikariCP-2.5.1.jar:?]
>           at java.util.Hashtable.forEach(Hashtable.java:879) [?:1.8.0_181]
>           at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.PropertyElf.setTargetFromProperties(PropertyElf.java:52)
>   [HikariCP-2.5.1.jar:?]
>           at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.initializeDataSource(PoolBase.java:315)
>   [HikariCP-2.5.1.jar:?]
>           at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.(PoolBase.java:108) [HikariCP-2.5.1.jar:?]
>           at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.(HikariPool.java:99)
>   [HikariCP-2.5.1.jar:?]
>           at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.(HikariDataSource.java:71)
>   [HikariCP-2.5.1.jar:?]
>           at net.corda.node.internal.DataSourceFactory.createDataSource(DataSourceFactory.kt:38)
>   [corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
>           at net.corda.node.internal.DataSourceFactory.createDataSource$default(DataSourceFactory.kt:35)
>   [corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
>           at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNodeKt.configureDatabase(AbstractNode.kt:910)
>   [corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
>           at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.initialiseDatabasePersistence(AbstractNode.kt:680)
>   [corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
>           at net.corda.node.internal.Node.initialiseDatabasePersistence(Node.kt:345)
>   [corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
>           at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.start(AbstractNode.kt:206)
>   [corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
>           at net.corda.node.internal.Node.start(Node.kt:359) [corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
>           at net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartup.startNode(NodeStartup.kt:145)
>   [corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
>           at net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartup.run(NodeStartup.kt:115) [corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
>           at net.corda.node.Corda.main(Corda.kt:13) [corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]

Answer (score 1):

> dataSourceProperties = {
>      "dataSourceClassName" : org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource
>      "dataSource.url" : "jdbc:Postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/postgres"
>      "dataSource.user" : "USER"
>      "dataSource.password" : "PASSWORD"
>   }
>   database = {
>      transactionIsolationLevel = READ_COMMITTED
>      schema = Notary
>   }

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solution was to rewrite database properties in `node.conf` using the following format:

```
"dataSourceProperties.dataSourceClassName"=org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource
```

It seems to be an issue where `"dataSourceProperties.dataSourceClassName"` is treated differently to `dataSourceProperties.dataSourceClassName` (no quotes).

Comment: This is a Corda 3.X bug and will be fixed in Corda 4.

Answer (score 0):

```
I tried alot and Finally I got solution. Again solution is based on type of Datasource and its version.
The root cause of this issue is PGSimpleDataSource does not have "url" property but other properties are there to form URL such as serverName, portNumber, DataBaseName. We did not specify those property because we specify URL that is incorrect for PGSimpleDataSource.

Solution:
remove url property of datasource 
// datasource..addDataSourceProperty(("url", databaseProp.getUrl()))

Add following things in place of URL.
    dataSource.addDataSourceProperty("serverName", "HOSTName/IP");
        //dataSource.addDataSourceProperty("serverName", "localhost");
        dataSource.addDataSourceProperty("portNumber", "5432");
        dataSource.addDataSourceProperty("databaseName", "testDB");

its is working fine after struggling a lot. :)
```